# ListView with headers (LongListSelector) for Xamarin.Forms

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, longlistselector

I'm looking for a view known as `LongListSelector` on the Windows Phone. It's a list view with group headers. Tapping a group header displays only a list of groups. Tapping a group on the list of groups hides the list of groups and scrolls the view to the selected group. It's a very useful way of groupping long lists with easy navigation between groups. If there are alternatives fit for the same purpose that would be also great.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can do this easily :)

The first thing you need to do is make sure your data source is a collection of collections. I would suggest an ObservableCollection> if you want maximum binding goodness. Then we can construct our listView as follows:

```
var listView = new ListView ();
listView.SetBinding (ListView.ItemsSourceProperty, "Data");
listView.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate (typeof (MyCell));
listView.GroupHeaderTemplate = new DataTemplate (typeof (MyHeaderCell));
listView.IsGroupingEnabled = true;
listView.GroupShortNameBinding = new Binding ("Title");
```

In order, we first bind in our data, I am assuming the BindingContext here will be inherited from the page. Our data should be the collection of collections already mentioned.

Then we bind in our ItemTemplate as normal, we make a GroupHeaderTemplate, this will be the template shown in the list during normal scrolling. Next we enable grouping to tell the list to use the data as a grouped collection rather than a flat list.

Finally with all that done, we provide a binding for the GroupShortName. This binding is run against the collection for each group to grab out a string (or an object that will have ToString called on it) to produce the jump list as you showed in your screenshots.

For performance reasons you may want to ensure the ItemsSource is not set until everything else has been set to avoid the ListView attempting to realizing Cells in a partially configured state. This will not actually result in bugs, it just forces the ListView to do more work.